# Unhandled exception error, ON SOME computers

Tags: visual-studio, unhandled-exception

Need help, I get unhandled exception on friends computer but not mine.

```
    See the end of this message for details on invoking 
    just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

    ************** Exception Text **************
    System.Net.WebException: The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine
      at     Microsoft.VisualBasic.MyServices.Internal.WebClientCopy.DownloadFile(Uri address, String destinationFileName)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.Network.DownloadFile(Uri address, String destinationFileName, ICredentials networkCredentials, Boolean showUI, Int32 connectionTimeout, Boolean overwrite, UICancelOption onUserCancel)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.Network.DownloadFile(String address, String destinationFileName, String userName, String password, Boolean showUI, Int32 connectionTimeout, Boolean overwrite, UICancelOption onUserCancel)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.Network.DownloadFile(String address, String destinationFileName, String userName, String password, Boolean showUI, Int32 connectionTimeout, Boolean overwrite)
   at R3dP0is0n.Main.Button1_Click_1(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
R3dP0is0n
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/Shaun/Desktop/R3dP0is0n.exe
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualBasic
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualBasic/v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.Remoting
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Runtime.Remoting/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Runtime.Remoting.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

This happens when the user clicks a button to download a file. the code is below. I have tried multiple things but cannot get it to work. They dont have microsoft .net framework 4 instead all my friends have 4.5.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("C:\jb\jb.exe") Then

    Else


        MsgBox("R3DP0IS0N files not found. R3DP0IS0N will now attempt to download your files. Click 'Ok' To continue.")
        'jbinfo.Text = "Please wait as your file is being downloaded."
        'Dim wc As New WebClient
        'wc.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri("http://download1580.mediafire.com/01z84i3pd5mg/zdc0t0q6ny6eb6d/r3dp0is0n.exe"), "C:\jb\jb.exe")
        My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("http://download1580.mediafire.com/01z84i3pd5mg/zdc0t0q6ny6eb6d/r3dp0is0n.exe", "C:\jb\jb.exe", "", "", True, 500, True) '

    End If
```

Comment: You need to find out what the differences are between the two computers. Does the other computer have the same version of .NET installed? Does it have the client version installed? etc.

Comment: Yes we have the same programs. And we bouth have client version. And it works on my virtual box xp that just has .net framework 4